# Import Works When Running Flask App, But Not When Running File Directly

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask app with the following file structure:

```
.env
app.py
config.py
/main_app
  __init__.py
  main.py
  /api
    api.py
    extra.py
    /models
      mod1.pkl
      mod2.pkl
```

In the `api.py` file, I have the following line:

`from .extra import str2bool, load_model_pipelines, load_explainers, generate_shap_chart_data`

When I call `flask run` from the console everything starts up fine.  However, when I go to run `api.py` directly I get the following error message:  `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

If I change `.extra` to `extra` then everything works fine.

I find this puzzling.  Why would it work one way when the app is run but a different way when run separately?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3)

Comment: Yes, but maybe not in the way I hoped :(  Seems complicated

Comment: Yeah, it could be better but it's really not that bad. I'd recommend using a more conventional directory structure. See [this for example](https://realpython.com/python-application-layouts/)